# ng2-auto-complete default selection on reactive form

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-reactive-forms

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-auto-complete on my Angular 5 application and this is how my input works

HTML:

```
<input
          id="shipper"
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          formControlName="shipper"
          auto-complete
          [source]="searchShipper.bind(this)"
          value-formatter="name"
          list-formatter="(id) name"
          (valueChanged)="onShipperSelected($event)"
          autocomplete="off"
        />
```

now I need to select a default value without using [(ngModel)] since it is deprecated to use with formControlName in Angular 6. It works when I use:

```
[(ngModel)]="defaultValue"
```

and when I try to set default value with patchValue:

```
const obj = {id: '1', name: 'test'};

this.form.patchValue({
  shipper: obj.toString()
});
```

or

```
const obj = {id: '1', name: 'test'};

this.form.patchValue({
  shipper: obj
});
```

it shows `[object Object]` on the input field,
any way to fix this on reactive forms?

Comment: value-formatter="name", it means it use the key 'name' from the selected object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand purpose of `value-formatter`. Here is example from [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-auto-complete#attributes):

```
myValueFormatter(data: any): string {
  return `(${data[id]}) ${data[value]}`;
}
```

If you want to define object property to display you should use `display-property-name` instead.

Here is the working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g4adbz).

Comment: it worked and showing default value when i use `display-property-name` instead but now the value when i submit the form is the `name` property and i want the submit value to be the id of the object or the complete object itself

Comment: use `value-formatter` and rewrite this example to return your `name` property for example: `return data.name;`

Comment: i again removed display-property-name and used: value-formatter="shipperValueFormatter" and on typescript i have shipperValueFormatter(shipper: any): string {
    console.log('it called', shipper);
    return shipper.name;
  }, the input value is again [object Object] and the shipperValueFormatter is never called, am i missing something?

Comment: Check edited answer. I wrote a simple example. Combination of `display-property-name` and `list-formatter` seems to work.

Comment: it worked thanks!, i find another solution here https://github.com/ng2-ui/auto-complete as well, it has a property value-property-name="id" which makes it simple to bind value and display property separately with display-property-name="name", ur solution worked as well!